# Drop down list and values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, html

I having a problem in setting the values of dropdown list. Here I am pasting my code.

HTML Code:

```
<form ng-submit="save()">
<table style=" table-layout: fixed;" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Section</th>
      <th>Names</th>
      <th>Marks</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>5th class</td>
      <td>
       <select id="5thclass" ng-model="setmarks.5thclass" ng-options="val for val in studentname">
            <option ng-init="setmarks.5thclass=studentname[0]" selected="selected"></option>
        </select>
        </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="5thclass" ng-model="setmarks.marks.5thclass"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    <div class="sub" class="btn-group">
        <input id="savebutton" type="submit" ng-click="Submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div><br />
</form>
```

Here is my angularjs code :

```
  $scope.studentname = ["abc","pqr","xyz"];

$scope.save = function(){

  $http.post('/savemarks', $scope.setmarks).success(function(data){
              console.log("posted data successfully");
              console.log( JSON.stringify(data));
            }).error(function(data){
              console.error("Error posting data");
            })
}
```

And finally here is my express.js set up. Where I am saving the form details in to file.

```
app.post('/savemarks',urlencodedParser,function(req,res){
  fs.appendFile(writecost_file,JSON.stringify(req.body,null,1),function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      console.log("File saved"); 
    }
  });
});
```

Output is in the json form:

```
{"5thclass":"abc","marks":{"5thclass":66}}
```

I want output should be of form.

```
{"5thclass":"abc","marks":{"abc":66}}
```

In the marks column i want student name instead of class name. Can any one help me . Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using setmarks.marks.5thclass inside the ng-model directive in your html. Because of that 5thclass is treated as a property of the marks object. That is why it is given as `"marks":{"5thclass":66}`
. You have to create the json object you are expecting manually in controller after save event is fired. As below. Hope this will help to you.

```js
 var st = '{"5thclass" : "' + $scope.setmarks.5thclass + '","marks":{"' + $scope.setmarks.5thclass + '":' + $scope.setmarks.marks.5thclass + '} }';
 var obj = JSON.parse(st);
```

**Note:** Don't use number as first character in property like setmarks.5thclass. This will consider as a syntax error while compiling the expression and will throw error.

Comment: Great, happy to hear that.